# Javascript capture console.trace() instead of writing it to console

Tags: javascript

I want to get the trace of a method called, so I'm using `console.trace()` however, this is dumping the trace to the console itself which I don't want to do. Instead, I want to capture the result, then do some processing it.

How can I achieve that? I know of 3rd party npm modules that do this, but I want to keep this as vanilla JS as possible.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the `.stack` property of a thrown error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function getStackTrace() {
  const { stack } = new Error("A senseless error message, this isnt one");
  return stack.substr(stack.indexOf("\n", stack.indexOf("\n") + 1));
}

function nestingOnProgress() {
  console.log("You will see my origin below:", getStackTrace());
}

nestingOnProgress();
```

Comment: @paulpro I don't know why I haven't thought about it, I should probably stop answering for today ...